# Word Order で And に before topic

Tags: grammar, particles, time, word-order

I am Slightly confused about the word order for に And で

Are both of these examples correct and the only difference the emphasis?

> 私は夏に公園で先生に会います: **I** am meeting my teacher at the park in the summer
>
> 夏に公園で私は先生に会います:**In the summer at the park** I am meeting my teacher

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I don't think word order matters here, since there's a particle marking each event. は for the topic, に for the time and で for the location.

Comment: I think your understanding is correct. Phrase order only affects, as you said, where the emphasis is placed in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asa9ohan and Jak said, In Japanese, the word order does not matter, that’s possible due to the existence of particles.

As long as your understanding and usage of particles is correct, the sentence will be correct.

In short, both sentences are right.